# How do I compare 2 strings in Pascal?

Tags: string, pascal

So I have 2 strings and I want to be able to say if the 2 strings are the same or not. The only problem is im filling the string 1 character by 1 using a while so if I use length/ord it doesn't work properly. I guess if you see the code im working with you will have an easier tas helping me out, so I'll just paste it here.

```
var
  cad1, cad2: string;
  car: char;
  icad1, icad2: integer;

begin
  car := 'o';
  icad1 := 1;
  icad2 := 1;

  write('Write the cad1: ');

  while (car<>'.') do begin
    car := readkey;
    cad1 := car;
    write(car);
    inc(icad1);
  end;

  car := 'o';
  writeln;

  write('Write thecad2: ');

  while (car <> '.') do begin
    car := readkey;
    cad2 := car;
    write(car);
    inc(icad2);
  end;

  writeln;
end.
```

Comment: Your `cad1` and `cad2` need to start as empty strings (*e.g.*, `cad1 := '';`) then append the new character to the string in your `while` loop, (*e.g.*, `cad1 := cad1 + car;`).

Comment: `inc(icad1)` isn't even valid. You can't increment a `string` type in Pascal. Your must be getting compilation errors. In addition to my prior suggestion, you must just get rid of these `inc`s. When you've read in the strings character by character as you seem to want to do, then you can compare them using the answer that @asd-tm gave.

Answer (score 2):

You have just to do :

```
CompareText(cad1, cad2)
```

it will return 0 if the two string are the same.

http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/comparetext.html

Comment: Dear @baddger964, You need to emphasize that the proposed `CompareText` function is **case insensitive**. This might confuse the OP if he is not expecting it and may give false-positive results if the user wishes to strictly compare the strings but not the text in them.

Comment: @lurker If you prefer this way of comparison, why not to use `SameText` function instead of `CompareText` in your edit? It will give a boolean resuslt for **case insensitive** comparison of strings. By the way, the OP did not specify if he needed case sensitive or insensitive comparison. And as I assume, we can not decide that for him. So I would advice to keep the previous edit of badger964 answer.

Comment: @asd-tm it's not my answer. I didn't suggest it.

Comment: @lurker I am sorry then. I thought it could be your edit. I saw the primary answer of baddger964 and then the version edited by you.

Comment: @asd-tm ah, my edit was strictly formatting. I didn't modify the answer.

Comment: You can also use '>' and '<' operators !

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. For example: the line `cad1:=car;` assigns the character to a string. That means that the resulting string contains only one character equal to car. All the previous inputs are lost.

The simpliest way to input the strings and compare them is the following:

```
write('Write the cad1: ');
readln(cad1);
write('Write thecad2: ');
readln(cad2);

write(cad1=cad2);
readln;
```